# How to create a query that returns only records in one table without a foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I create a query that returns only records in one table that have no foreign key relations with a particular attribute? I'm not even sure how to properly formulate the question, so I'm giving an example below:

I have Table B. It has an ID and other stuff that's not important.
I have Table C. It has an ID, an attribute (call it Available) which is only ever 'Yes' or 'No'.

Each record in Table B may have zero or more records in Table C related to it. They are connected by Table BC_Line, where each record has a FK for B_ID and a FK for C_ID. Hence, if records C_ID=1 and C_ID=2 are related to B_ID=1, then BC_Line has two records: (B_ID_FK=1 C_ID_FK=1) and (B_ID_FK=1 C_ID_FK=2).

I want a query that returns ONLY records in B that have NO associated records in C with C_Available='No'. A record in B might have several related records in C, all with 'Yes', and that would be shown. A record in B might have several related records in C all with 'No', that would NOT be shown. A record in B might also have records in C, some 'Yes' and some 'No', but that record would still not be shown. All related C records must be 'Yes'.

I'm not sure how to do it. I understand how to create queries and how to do Joins, but I do not know how to combine them in such a way as to get what I want. It's possible this is a well known problem, but I haven't been able to find the answer, partly because I have difficulty articulating my problem.

For the record, I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TableC c
                  WHERE c.C_Available='No'
                    AND b.B_ID_FK =c.C_ID);
```

Note! I've assumed that `c.C_Available` is defined as NOT NULL and it could hold only `Yes/No` values.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, but I'm afraid it's not working for me. It comes back with every record in B, rather than just the ones with only 'Yes'.

Comment: @cdpautsch Please prepare http://rextester.com demo with sample data. Then I will check it.

Comment: I'm afraid I never used that before and wasn't able to get it working quite right, but what I have is here: http://rextester.com/ZXCW23029. C_V_Check is a replacement for C_Available due to changes in how the project I'm working on is coming together. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `left join` method.

```
select b.*
from tableB b left join bc_line on b.b_id = bc.b_id
left join tableC c on bc.c_id = c.c_id
   and c.c_available = 'No'

where c.c_id is null
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working for me. It just returns back all the B records. However, if I swap c.c_available='no' to 'yes', then it only returns one record which has one 'yes' and one 'no' (while the other has two 'yes's).